# How to handle "Unable to start activity java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-viewgroup, onsaveinstancestate

After updating my app, crashlytics started reporting this issue. with this logcat

```
androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:149)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:313)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:106)
com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.LockScreenActivity.onCreate (LockScreenActivity.java:87)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7154)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7145)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1225)
```

When I look questions with same error code. I saw it causes because of the iteration in lists. In this activity there is no iteration. Even more there is no list or array. So it is not same question with others. The line it says it failed:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //(LockScreenActivity.java:87)

    if(new NewVersionControl(this).CheckVersion())
            {
                new NewSharedPrefs(this).LookForNewSharedPrefs();

            handleAlarms = new HandleAlarms(this);
            handleAlarms.SetAlarmManager(); }
        else
        {if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                this.setShowWhenLocked(true);
            }
            else {            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            }

            setContentView(R.layout.opaque_full_screen_lock_screen);

            SharedPrefsHandler sharedPrefsHandler = new SharedPrefsHandler(this);


            //Ads initialized
            MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.app_id));

            SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration =
                    new SdkConfiguration.Builder(getString(R.string.twitter_banner_ad_unit_id)).build();
    MoPub.initializeSdk(this, sdkConfiguration, null);
    Declarations();
    GetRemoteConfig();
    if(handleRealmInit == null) {handleRealmInit = new HandleRealmInit(this);}
    lockScreenRealm = handleRealmInit.GetRealmInstance();
    BindData();
     if(sharedPrefsHandler.GetPref(SharedPrefsHandler.IS_PREMIUM).getIntegerValue()== 0) 
    {
LoadAd();
}
                if(lockScreenFact!= null)   {
                    if(lockScreenFact.isValid())
                    {
                        ReportProperties();
                    }
                }
            }
```

So I think it occurs due to handling of views or view group by Android. But I couldn't define or reproduce the problem. I am stuck at this point.

Thank you for reading this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentModificationException means you are trying to add/remove elements from an array while iterating over it without an interator.

What is inside your onCreate method ?

Comment: Thank you for response. I added on create. There is no array inside OnCreate or its methods. I started to have crashes after implementing different Ad libraris. Can it cause because of the libraries ? (got after implementing MoPub Mediation part)

Comment: what is on line 87 of the onCreate?

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //(LockScreenActivity.java:87)

Comment: does this activity inherit from something other than the provided android activity classes ?

Comment: public class LockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 

No it doesnt

Comment: do you have anything to do with lists/arrays in your code ?

Comment: First thank you for your patience, I really appreciated it. I checked two times, now will look for third. I have no array nor list and I just started to have it recently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206475/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-eren-tufekci).

Comment: Have you managed to find the root cause? I'm struggling with this error where in my code I'm not using any arrays / lists.